# Signing up household type memberships

Tags: wordpress, civimember, 4.6.10

The organization wants to have the ability to have multiple contacts for custom membership types of Household, Sustaining, Patron. I've set up the membership types for this, with the "household member is" relationship setting. This works only if the primary contact type is "Household". The problem with this is that the public facing membership sign up form (contribution form) only lets you sign up as the Individual contact type. Is there some way to tie the membership type to the contact type at the time the contact is created?

This looks like the most relevant forum post:
https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=27970.0
Looks like there might be a way with drupal, but not wordpress. Just how much additional code would this require? -- I could write this very quickly with c#... but php/wordpress never.

Comment: i was going to point you to that thread but you found it already. my comment there about "would another way to approach it be to have the 'on behalf of' approach reworked so it could also work for HouseHolds" still seems valid

Comment: Paul, did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to extend to code which makes the 'on behalf of Organisation' approach work for Households as well.

The membership type would be set up so that an individual 'inherits' the membership based on a specified relationship.

When an Individual signs up they either be given the option of selecting 'on behalf of', or the 'household' membership page would be set up to require it.

The outcome of a new membership would be that the individual is created, a household is created, the membership 'belongs' to the household, a permissioned* relationship would be created between the individual and the household, and due to that relationship the individual would 'inherit' the membership provided in the settings of the Membership Type.

- my understanding of the 'on behalf of Organisation' code is that for the individual to be able to renew on behalf of the organisation (ie for their Organisation to prefill on the form if the user is logged in or using a checksum link) the individual is set up with the 'employee of' Relationship, they are also set as 'current employee' and the relationship is set so the individual is 'permissioned over the organisation'.

For a household equivalent, there is no equivalent for 'current employee' so the solution would need to step around that but that sounds fairly trivial.

Comment: To me this is a useless comment - unless you fully explain with an example. What you need to do to boost anything is provide more accepted solutions to questions. You are trying to game the system without providing any value to the users.

Comment: Hi Paul - probably a fair comment and one reason i put the NB in there to be clear about why I was doing this. What would it take to flesh this out so it did seem a substantive answer. I cannot propose the steps required to get this beyond the hackneyed "if you have funds to get this feature added then I expect the core team or a development shop would be happy to take it on.

Comment: The underlying reason i added any answer, was that making 'on behalf of' work for Households would totally suit your use case as I understood it, and is a 'feature request' that has been bouncing around for a while and my hope is that by shining more light on it, perhaps someone can step up and deliver it

Comment: okay - how does the above look now? it may not help you directly but i hope it leaves a useful trail for anyone else who stumbles upon this. Thanks for the poke to improve it.